# unhashable type list error, although using string

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am working with a dictionary and at some point am getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./process_blasthit.py", line 637, in <module>
    prot_names_dict_path, options)
  File "./process_blasthit.py", line 491, in extract_dists
    prot_names_dict, options)
  File "./process_blasthit.py", line 326, in scan_file
    product, options)
  File "./process_blasthit.py", line 253, in add_to_env_dict
    if product not in env_dict[str(cessor_type)]:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

As you can see I already tried converting the key (cessor_type) to a string before accessing it in the dictionary but it still doesn't work.

Also, when I print out type(cessor_type) just before it tells me it is a string instance.

Furthermore, the first few accessions (i.e. env_dict[str(censor_type)]) work just fine.

Here's the function where I try to access the dictionary:

```
def add_to_env_dict(env_queue, cessor_type, env_dict, succ_counter, 
                    product, options):

  if cessor_type=="succ":
    env_queue_new=env_queue[1:]
  elif cessor_type=="pred":
    env_queue_new=env_queue[max(0,len(env_queue)-options["env_k"]):]
  else:
      stderr.write("Cessor type needs to be either \"succ\" or \"pred\"")
      raise SystemExit

  # the key of env_dict is ["pred"/"succ"][product of blasthit]
  # the values are env_k-tuples (stored as lists) of predecessors/successors 
  # with additional information on each predecessor/successor
  print(type(cessor_type))
  if product not in env_dict[str(cessor_type)]:
    env_dict[cessor_type][product]=[env_queue_new]
  else:
    env_dict[cessor_type][product].append(env_queue_new)

  return env_dict
```

Maybe I'm overseeing something obvious here but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm grateful for any hint.

Comment: It appears that `product` is the actual problem here, not `cessor_type`.

Comment: What is `product`?

Comment: yes you're right, thanks a lot!!